# Where should I insert the titlesec package?

Tags: packages, installing

I am writing a thesis and I want the chapter and its heading right aligned.
On searching in TEX I got an answer to download the `titlesec` package.

I downloaded it but I don't know where to insert the package.

Comment: Do you need help to install the package or to load it? Packages are loaded using `\usepackage[<optional options>]{<package name>}`, i.e. in your case use `\usepackage{titlesec}` in the preamble.

Comment: wen i use \usepackage{titlesec} a dialogue box appears asking for the path where the package is.When i selected random package repository, it says titlesec.sty not found.

Comment: I downloaded the package and saved it in my downloads. Then copied the folder titlesec to the folder where miktex 2.8 is installed in C drive. I need to know where I should copy  the folder titlesec so that while compiling its used by the program

Comment: I may need more packages in future. Please tell me where to save these packages so that it can be accessed by the program

Comment: You can install packages using the MikTeX package manager. It even can install missing packages on the fly. Try to compile a document with `\usepackage{titlesec}` and see if there is an error.

Comment: how to install using miktek package manager?? from where will i get miktek package manager?

Comment: Please see the official website of MiKTeX for this: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html. A manual install is also described in [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/2975) .

Comment: I close this question now, since it's about basic use of MiKTeX, which is described in the MiKTeX manual, Martin has alrady provided a link.